# Getting video information for a list of files output as a csv or text file

Tags: ffmpeg, script, video-streaming, ffprobe

I am looking for a tool or method where I can cycle through a list of files/links and output some information or metadata in text format like this:

```
        Name           Resolution   FPS   Video Bitrate   Audio Bitrate   V-Codec   A-Codec  
---------------------- ------------ ----- --------------- --------------- --------- --------- 
wedding camera 1.mp4   1920*1080     50             2.3              92   h264      aac      
wedding mobile 5.mp4   1280*720      25               2              92   h264      aac
```

I am looking at ffmpeg or ffprobe. Can use windows or linux but noty sure how to go about parsing information from there.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
```

I want to extend this to using m3u lists as well. So if there is an already built program that does this please let me know.

Comment: There's no existing program that does this, AFAIK. What have you already tried? `ffprobe` or `mediainfo` can be used on a single file, and then all you'd have to do is format the information in whatever way you want it. This depends on whether you can write a script (e.g. in Bash or Python) that does that. For example, run `ffprobe -hide_banner -show_streams -of json <video>` to get the info as JSON, which can then be re-formatted into CSV or whatever output you need.

Comment: what would be better to use, mediainfo or ffprobe? is medianinfo capable of reading a web stream?

Comment: I'd rather use ffprobe if you plan on reading web streams or M3U files.

Answer (score 0):

I used EXIFTOOL:

```
exiftool -csv -r -FileName -FileTypeExtension -FileSize -FileType -Duration -Format -ImageSize -VideoFrameRate -VideoFieldOrder -MajorBrand -CompressorID -CompressorName -HandlerDescription -AudioFormat -AudioChannels -AudioSampleRate -HistorySoftwareAgent -BitDepth -Directory "/dir-to-scan" >output.csv
```